# I want to print in color in python terminal, why are my colors limited to 8?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I've been trying several different python modules for printing in colour. colorama, termcolor, etc.

All of these only allow me to print in 8 different colors.

```
    grey
    red
    green
    yellow
    blue
    magenta
    cyan
    white
```

Is there a module that will allow me to print in colors other than these such as 'orange' or is it impossible to print in colors other than these?

Comment: There are many packages that help with colored terminal output. Did you try Googling? I was able to find 5 within a minute of searching.

Comment: Also, check out a full list of ANSI escape codes: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php As well, take a look at the wikipidea page on ANSI escape codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code @stavro

Comment: I tried a lot of modules one site said I could get 'orange' with print('\033[33m' + 'testing'+ '\x1b[0m') but it's just a dark brown. Other modules i tried have Foregrounds and backgrounds that vary, but only in permutations of grey
    red
    green
    yellow
    blue
    magenta
    cyan
    white.